# Merge two flat arrays on shared numeric associative keys to form a 2d associative array

Tags: php, arrays, merge, mapping, associative-array

I have **two associative array**:

First Array:

```
$first_array = [
    1  => 'Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens (2015)',
    5  => 'Avatar (2009)',
    7  => 'Black Panther (2018)',
    10 => 'Avengers: Infinity War (2018)',
    11 => 'Titanic (1997)',
    18 => 'Jurassic World (2015)',
    20 => 'Marvel's The Avengers (2012)',
    25 => 'Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi (2017)'
];
```

And the **Second associative array**:

Second Array:

```
$second_array = [
    1  => '3 star',
    5  => '5 star',
    7  => '3 star',
    18 => '4 star',
    20 => '3 star',
    25 => '4 star'
];
```

Here **key of first & second array** is the movie_id.
How to merge the resulted array like this:

```
$resulted_array = [
    1  => [
        'name'  => 'Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens (2015)', 
        'rating'=> '3 star'
    ],
    5  => [
        'name'  => 'Avatar (2009)', 
        'rating'=> '5 star'
    ],
    7  => [
        'name'  => 'Black Panther (2018)', 
        'rating'=> '3 star'
    ],
    18 => [
        'name'  => 'Jurassic World (2015)', 
        'rating'=> '4 star'
    ],
    20 => [
        'name'  => 'Marvel's The Avengers (2012)', 
        'rating'=> '3 star'
    ],
    25 => [
        'name'  => 'Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi (2017)' 
        'rating'=> '4 star'
    ]
];
```

I'm doing this by using loop, But is their any optimal solution? Or what is the optimal solution for this kind of job on a large data set?

Comment: is your loop slow? We don't really do code review here, not that you've posted any. There is another StackExchange site for that and you could check there to see if your question is suitable for it. If you have an actual real-life performance issue you'd like help with, then please provide code and details so we can look into it. In general terms, a loop sounds reasonable to work on an array. Maybe there's some PHP array functions you could potentially make use of to shorten your code, but chances are they probably just use loops internally anyway.

Comment: Very trivially, there is http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php you could look at. Maybe it helps you, maybe not, you can study it.

Comment: If your code is working and you just need to improve it, your question might be better of over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's good to strive for improvements, but with modern resources (high RAM CPU power etc) it's not necessary to overly worry about doing this for the sake of it. Sometimes code just has to be what it has to be. If you have to foreach an array to split it or merge another one in where array_merge wont cut it then so be it :)

Comment: Do you really need to create that array? If you only need to echo the movie and rating there is no need to create that array as you have the key to post the movie and the same key is to the ratings. But if you json_encode I see why you need it.

Comment: Let's see your loop; maybe we could speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

1) It would be better to create the single array when you create the two other arrays. I appreciate this is not always possible, but for example if you have two queries, try using one query with a join (I'm guessing a bit here).

2) If this is simply for display purposes, and eg you don't need the main keys preserving and don't need to create the array with the words "name" and "rating" (as you already know this and it's dupe info) then this is a fairly streamlined approach:

```
$merged = array_map(function () { return func_get_args(); }, $first_array, $second_array);
```

The two arrays are from your question.
This will output:

```
array(8) {
  [0] =&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0] =&gt;
    string(49) "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens (2015)"
    [1] =&gt;
    string(6) "3 star"
  }
  [1] =&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0] =&gt;
    string(13) "Avatar (2009)"
    [1] =&gt;
    string(6) "5 star"
  }
```

Then you can just loop that array and each sub array's keys are in order of "name" and "rating", e.g.:

```
foreach ($merged as $data) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $data[0];
    echo 'Rating: ' . $data[1];
}
```

3) Just loop array 1 and echo the corresponding matching key in the other array. e.g.:

```
foreach ($first_array as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $value;
    echo 'Rating: ';
    echo !empty($second_array[$key]) ? $second_array[$key] : 'Unknown';
}
```

If you need this data elsewhere then doing this before hand and setting a new array would return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This task is a simple matter of iterating the second array and accessing data from the first array based on shared keys.

For a functional-style approach, use `array_reduce()` to preserve first level keys. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/U33lD))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_keys($second_array),
        fn($result, $k) => $result + [$k => ['name' => $first_array[$k], 'rating' => $second_array[$k]]],
        []
    )
);
```

For a classic loop, the iterated syntax is a bit simpler and easier to read.  New associative rows need only be pushed into the result array with their original numeric key as the first level key. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/01Dee))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($second_array as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = ['name' => $first_array[$k], 'rating' => $second_array[$k]];
}
var_export($result);
```